# Byte array with negative byte values can't be converted to String using UTF-8

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, byte

Consider this is byte array,
`byte[] by = [2, 126, 33, -66, -100, 4, -39, 108]`

then if we execute the below code and print it,

```
String utf8_str = new String(by, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(utf8_str);
```

the output is:

```
\~!���l
```

Where all the negative values are converted to '�' which means that the byte with -ve value is not in the UTF-8 character set.
But the UTF-8 character set has a range of 0 to 255.

If only 0-127 can be shown in +ve in the form of byte datatype, then the numbers greater than 127 can never be used when encoding to UTF-8 character set as Java does not support unsigned byte value.

Any solution for this?

I needed to encode a byte array to UTF-8 character String and get the byte array back from the UTF-8 character String.

But all the character are encoded and retrieved properly except '�'.

when I try to retrieve '�' (i.e, print it's UTF-8 Unicode), it gives some other Unicode rather than the Unicode of the encoded character.

Comment: `-66` or `0xBE` is not valid as first byte in UTF-8  (UTF-8 is NOT a characters set, but an encoding standard)

Comment: BTW negative values are not the problem (e.g. `byte[] { -61, -97 }` will be converted to `"ß"`) and it is Java that interprets bytes greater than 127 as negative

Comment: You are confused. It seems like your real problem is about "I needed to encode a byte array to UTF8 character String and get the byte array back from the UTF8 character String." Can you show a [mcve] of that problem instead? I can assure you this is not about negatives or positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You can't decode arbitrary bytes as UTF-8, because some byte streams are not conforming UTF-8 streams. If you need to represent arbitrary bytes as String, use something like Base64:

```
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arbitraryBytes);
```

## Not all byte sequences are valid UTF-8

UTF-8 has [very specific rules about what bytes sequences are allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding). The short version is:

- a byte in the range 0x00-0x7F can stand alone (and represents the equivalent character as its ASCII encoding).
- a byte in the range 0xC2-0xF4 is a leading byte that starts a multi-byte sequence with the exact value indicating the number of continuation bytes
- a byte in the range 0x80-0xBF is a continuation byte that has to come after a leading byte and possibly some other continuation bytes.

There's a few more rules and nuances to it, but that's the basic idea.

As you can see there are several byte values (0xC0, 0xC1, 0xF5-0xFF) that can't appear in a well-formed UTF-8 stream at all. Additionally some other bytes can only occur in specific sequences. For example a leading byte can never be followed by another leading byte or a stand-alone byte. Similarly a stand-alone byte must never be followed by a continuation byte.

Note about "negative values": `byte` in Java is a signed data type. But the signed/unsigned debate is not relevant for this topic, as it only matters when calculating with the value or when printing it. It's **the** 8-bit type to use in Java and the fact that the byte `0xBE` is represented as `-66` in Java is mostly a visual distinction. For the purposes of this discussion "negative values" is equivalent to "byte values between 0x80 and 0xFF". It just so *happens* that the non-negative values are exactly the stand alone bytes in UTF-8 and are converted just fine.

All this means that **decoding arbitrary `byte[]` as UTF-8** will not work in most cases!**

## Then why doesn't `new String(...)` throw an exception?

But if `arbitraryBytes` contains a `byte[]` that isn't valid UTF-8, then why doesn't [`new String(arbitraryBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.nio.charset.Charset)) throw an exception?

Good question! Maybe it should, but the designers of Java have decided that this specific way of decoding a `byte[]` into a `String` should be lenient:

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string. The `CharsetDecoder` class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.

The "default replacement string" in this case is simply the Unicode character [U+FFFD Replacement Character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), which looks like a question mark in a filled rhombus: �

And as the documentation states, there **is** of course a way to decode a `byte[]` to a `String` and getting a real exception when it doesn't go right:

```
byte[] arbitraryBytes = new byte[] { 2, 126, 33, -66, -100, 4, -39, 108 };
CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder().onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
String string = decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(arbitraryBytes)).toString();
```

This code will throw an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:274)
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:820)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

## Okay, but I really need a String!

We have realized that decoding your `byte[]` to a `String` using UTF-8 doesn't work. One *could* use ISO-8859-1, which maps all 256 byte values to characters, but that would result in Strings with many unprintable control characters, which would be quite cumbersome to handle.

### Use Base64

The usual solution for this is to [use Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

```
// encode byte[] to Base64
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arbitraryBytes);
System.out.println(base64);
// decode Base64 to byte[]
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arbitraryBytes, decoded));
```

With the same `arbitraryBytes` as before this will print

```
An4hvpwE2Ww=
true
```

Base64 is a common choice because it is able to represent arbitrary bytes with a reasonable number of characters (on average it will take about a third more characters than it has input bytes, depending on the exact formatting and/or padding used).

There are [a few variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) of Base64, which are used in various situations. Particularly common is the use of the URL- and filename-safe variant, which ensures that no characters with any special meaning in URLs and file names are used. Luckily it is [directly supported in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html#getUrlEncoder()).

### Format as a hex string

Base64 is neat and useful, but it somewhat obfuscates the individual byte values. Occasionally we want a format that allows us to interpret the values in some way. For this [a hexadecimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) of the data might be more useful, even though it takes up more characters than Base64:

```
// encode byte[] to hex
String hexFormatted = HexFormat.of().formatHex(arbitraryBytes);
System.out.println(hexFormatted);
// decode hex to byte[]
byte[] decoded = HexFormat.of().parseHex(hexFormatted);
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arbitraryBytes, decoded));
```

This will print

```
027e21be9c04d96c
true
```

This hex format (without separator) will take exactly 2 characters per input byte, making this format more verbose than Base64.

If you're not yet on Java 17 or later, there are [plenty of other ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java).

## But I've already converted my `byte[]` to `String` using UTF-8 and I really need my original data back.

Sorry, but you most likely can't. Unless you were very lucky and your original `byte[]` happened to be a well-formed UTF-8 stream, the conversion to `String` will have lost some data and you will only be able to recover a fraction of your original `byte[]`.

```
String badString = new String(arbitraryBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] recoveredBytes = badString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This will give you *something* but every time your input contained a encoding error, this will contain the byte sequence 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD (or -17 -65 -67, when interpreted as signed bytes and printed in decimal). That byte sequence is what UTF-8 encodes the U+FFFD Replacement Character as.

Depending on the *specific* input (and even the specific implementation of the UTF-8 decoder!) each replacement character can replace one or more bytes, so you can't even reliably tell the size of the original input array like this.